# React native File move Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,

Tags: react-native, fs

I'm trying to take photo and move it into a folder which created by app.

Here's all my code
It saves photo to folder but not moving to custom folder

**Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

    makeDirectory = () => {
      console.log('makeDirectory  içi');
      console.log('RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath');
      console.log(RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath);
      const AppFolder = 'DirNameyouwant';
      const DirectoryPath =
        RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath +
        '/Android/data/com.myTempApp/files/Pictures/' +
        AppFolder;

      RNFS.mkdir(DirectoryPath)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log('result', result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.warn('err', err);
        });
    };
    const takePhotoFromCamera = () => {
      ImagePicker.openCamera({
        compressImageMaxWidth: 300,
        compressImageMaxHeight: 300,
        cropping: true,
        compressImageQuality: 0.7,
        saveToPhotos: true,
      }).then((image) => {
        console.log('you take photo');
        console.log(image);
        console.log('Image pat '+image.path);
        
        const    AppFolder    =     'DirNameyouwant';
      const DirectoryPath= RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath +'/Android/data/com.myTempApp/files/Pictures/'+ AppFolder;
       

        RNFS.moveFile(image.path, DirectoryPath)
          .then((success) => {
            console.log('file moved!');
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
          });
        //this.bs.current.snapTo(1);
      });
    };

    const choosePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
      ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        cropping: true,
        compressImageQuality: 0.7,
      }).then((image) => {
        console.log('Foto SECTIN helal');
        console.log(image.path);
        //setImage(image.path);
        //this.bs.current.snapTo(1);
        const    AppFolder    =     'DirNameyouwant';
        const DirectoryPath= RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath +'/Android/data/com.myTempApp/files/Pictures/'+ AppFolder;
        RNFS.moveFile(image.path, DirectoryPath)
        .then((success) => {
          console.log('file moved!');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
        });
      });
    };
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
          <Text>Take Photo</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
          <Text>Choose From Library</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => makeDirectory()}>
          <Text>Cancel</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

the error it gives

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="22" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="22" android:required="true"/>
```

It all about it.

I just want to pick or capture image and move it to custom file. Thank you

I'm using thees  librariys and this is the simplest example of capturing image.

Comment: Aynone to help me please I have been waiting almost 24 hour

Comment: did the permission promp show?

Comment: Yes at the beginning

Comment: Did the create directory succeed?

Comment: Yes creates empty folder